# wget downloads malformed directories when using -r flag

Tags: linux, wget, github

I am trying to download a directory from github along with all the subdirectories and files. I don't want the whole repository.

I use this command

```
wget -np -nH --cut-dirs 4 -r -e robots=off https://github.com/uc-cdis/cdis-manifest/tree/master/data.bloodpac.org -P ~/prod_manifest/
```

However, while I am able to download some of the directories and structure, it doesn't seem form directories for all the folders. Specifically portal, hatchery and scaling are all malformed when they are downloaded. They aren't recognized as folder.

Comment: Some links there contain `blob` instead of `tree` and I *guess* this makes them out of the scope. I don't know `wget` well enough to tell you how to include them.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see an option to do this task with wget. However, if you are just concern about downloading the subfolder recursively then use svn.

Install subversion

```
sudo apt install subversion
```

Then replace `tree/master` with `trunk` and run the following command

```
svn checkout https://github.com/uc-cdis/cdis-manifest/trunk/data.bloodpac.org
```

There are few websites which can do this as well. https://kinolien.github.io/gitzip/